# How do I go from $\check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{F})$ to $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{F})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Let's say I have $\mathcal{F}= \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)$ for concreteness. Then what does a closed element of $\check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$ look like as an element of $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$? So I know you would just take the quotient
$$
\frac{ker: \check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \to \check{C}^2(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))}{Im: \check{C}^0(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \to \check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))}
$$

but one problem I'm having is that I have been taking my cover $\mathscr{U}$ to be the standard one, $U_0$, $U_1$, which works fine for $\check{C}^0$ and $\check{C}^1$ but on $\check{C}^2$, you need to take local sections on the intersection of three patches. But I only have two. Do I just need to take a different open cover? If so, what should it be? Or is there a better work-around?

Let's say I have $\mathcal{F}= \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)$ for concreteness. Then what does a closed element of $\check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$ look like as an element of $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$? Theoretically, you take the quotient

$$
\frac{ker: \check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \to \check{C}^2(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))}{Im: \check{C}^0(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \to \check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))}
$$

but one problem I'm having is that I have been taking my cover $\mathscr{U}$ to be the standard one, $U_0$, $U_1$, which works fine for $\check{C}^0$ and $\check{C}^1$ but on $\check{C}^2$, you need to take local sections on the intersection of three patches. But I only have two. Do I just need to take a different open cover? If so, what should it be? Or is there a better work-around?

Also, you know $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b)) \cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathscr{O}(-a-2))^* \oplus H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathscr{O}(-b-2))^*$ by Serre duality. This latter piece you can find a nice description of as a vector space so is there a convenient way to write your element of $\check{C}^1(\mathscr{U}, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$ as an element of $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathscr{O}(-a-2))^* \oplus H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathscr{O}(-b-2))^*$? Or if there is a better way to write the vector space $H^1((\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(b))$ that would work too. I just don't know how to do it without writing global sections.

Comment: I haven't read your full post, but cech covers with two elements the next group is zero. Namely, if you want to put it in your framework where you must always have infinite covers, just think about taking it to be $\{U_0,U_1,U_2,\ldots,\}$ with $U_i=\varnothing$ for $i>0$. in other words, all the higher groups are zero! So, $H^2$ is just the kernel of $C^2$ to $C^3$ (which is all of $C^2$!) modulo the image from $C^1$. So, it's just $C^2$ modulo the image of $C^1$.

Comment: Also, in general, there is a nice interpretation of the elements of $H^1$. I won't go into full detail here but, suffice it to say, that $H^1(X,\mathcal{F})$, for, say, $\mathcal{F}$ an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, is precisely $\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$. In other words, it's extensions of the form

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{F}\to 0$$

up to isomorphism.